# Creating two button methods Python

Tags: python, button

I am creating a program in Python that creates a shape based on user input. I need to create two functions to create buttons using [Zeller's graphic.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) file. One button needs to say Quit and the second needs to say Process. Here is what i have so far but as you can see, they are not in defined functions:

```
#create Quit button
quitButton = Text(Point(70,73), "Quit")
quitButton.draw(w)
Rectangle(Point(45, 50), Point(95,97)).draw(w)

#create Process button
enterButton = Text(Point(145,73), "Process")
enterButton.draw(w)
Rectangle(Point(120, 48), Point(170,98)).draw(w)
```

Here is a description of the necessary methods

- `createButton(text, pt1button, pt2button, win)` creates a rectangle with corner points `pt1button` and `pt2button` with centered text in window win
- `clickedButton(button, clickPt)` returns true/false if `clickPt` is in button.

I tried to create the function and received the following error.

Here is my function:

```
def createButton(text, pt1button, pt2button, win):
    button = Text(Point(pt1button, pt2button), text)
    button.draw(win)
```

Here is where I called the function:

```
createButton("Process",145,73,win) 
createButton("Quit",70,73,win)
```

Here is the error that was thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/project4FINAL.p‌​y", line 77, in <module> main()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/project4FINAL.p‌​y", line 27, in main buttonCreate("Process", 145,73, win)
NameError: global name 'win' is not defined
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: whats your question ? it looks like you know how to make a button ...

Comment: How would I format that code to satisfy the requirements of creating the two methods?

Comment: I would start with `def createButton(text,pt1,pt2,parent_window):`

Comment: I had created this previously, but it throws an error.

def createButton(text, pt1button, pt2button, win):
   button = Text(Point(pt1button, pt2button), text)
   button.draw(win)

Comment: well why dont you put what you tried and the error you got ...

Comment: createButton("Process",145,73,win)
createButton("Quit",70,73,win)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/project4FINAL.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/project4FINAL.py", line 27, in main
    buttonCreate("Process", 145,73, win)
NameError: global name 'win' is not defined

Comment: Put it in the question, not the comments.

Comment: @ebarr I just edited the question and included the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from looking at the code it looks like you want to create a callback function for each button and then assign each to the canvas via the `setMouseHandler` of method of `GraphWin`.

So from the example given in the API:

```
from graphics import *

def example_callback():
    print "I love unicorns!" 

def main():
    # win is a Canvas with a setMouseHandler method
    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
    c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
    c.draw(win)

    #Add a callback to the canvas
    c.cavas.setMouseHandler(example_callback)
    # or win.setMouseHandler(example_callback)

    win.getMouse() # Pause to view result
    win.close()    # Close window when done

main()
```

Unless you have bounds checking in you callbacks (to see which shape on the canvas the mouse is inside), you should only have one canvas per drawn shape.

An example following the use of a `createButton` function:

```
def createButton(text, pt1button, pt2button, win):
    button = Text(Point(pt1button, pt2button), text)
    button.draw(win)
    return button

def _callback(pt):
   print "I love unicorns!"
   print
   print "Mouse clicked at x=%d, y=%d"%(pt.x,pt.y)
   print

def test():
   win = GraphWin()
   win.setCoords(0,0,100,100)
   quitButton = createButton("Quit",70,73,win)
   Rectangle(Point(45, 50), Point(95,97)).draw(win)
   win.setMouseHandler(_callback)
   while True:
      win.getMouse()
   win.close()
```

Below is a complete example using a new Button object:

```
from graphics import *

class Button(object):
    def __init__(self, text, text_pos, rect_pos, win, callback):
        self.win = win
        self.text = Text(text_pos, text)
        self.text.draw(self.win)

        # the limits of the button will be defined by the rectangle                                                              
        self.coords = [rect_pos[0].x,rect_pos[0].y,rect_pos[1].x,rect_pos[1].y]
        self.rect = Rectangle(*rect_pos)
        self.rect.draw(self.win)

        # set the buttons callback
        self.callback = callback

    def _is_inside(self,click):
        limits = self.coords
        return  (limits[0] < click.x < limits[2]) and (limits[1] < click.y < limits[3])

class MyWindow(object):
    def __init__(self,coords=(0,0,100,100)):
        self.win = GraphWin()
        self.win.setCoords(*coords)

        # a list of all possible buttons
        self.buttons = []

        # register the master callback function
        self.win.setMouseHandler(self._callback)
        self._quit = False

        #create a quit and confess button with a custom create method
        self.create_button("Quit",(Point(10,10),Point(40,40)),Point(20,20),self.quit)
        self.create_button("Confess",(Point(50,50),Point(80,80)),Point(60,60),self.confess)

    def create_button(self,text,coords,text_coords,callback):
        button = Button(text,text_coords,coords,self.win,callback)
        # create a button and add it to our list of buttons
        self.buttons.append(button)

    def confess(self,point):
        print
        print "I love unicorns!"
        print

    def quit(self,point):
        self._quit = True
        self.win.close()

    # This function is called for any click on the canvas
    def _callback(self,point):
        # Need to do a coordinate transform here to get the click in the coordinates of the button
        x,y = self.win.trans.world(point.x,point.y)
        point = Point(x,y)
        print "Clicked at x=%d, y=%d"%(point.x,point.y)

        # cycle through buttons and execute all for which the clicked point lies inside their rectangle
        for button in self.buttons:
            if button._is_inside(point):
                button.callback(point)

    # a loop to keep getting mouse input
    def run(self):
        while not self._quit:
            try:
                self.win.getMouse()
            except GraphicsError:
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = MyWindow()
    x.run()
```

Comment: I am confused as to how this relates to creating the buttons using the functions.

Comment: Q: What is a button? A: An area on the screen which when clicked on executes a function. This is showing you how to give your button a function to execute when clicked. Currently you are just creating shapes on the screen. If you want those shapes to be usable as buttons, you need to bind the underlying canvas to a mouse click and set a callback function to be executed.

Comment: I've added some extra code to show how you could potentially use a create buttons function. There are several problems with this example. The biggest one is that the code should be encapsulated in an object so that the callback can access shared state. The other is that will execute `_callback` when the canvas is clicked anywhere. You will need to put boundary checks in the call back that relate to a specific functionality (like quit or refresh).

Comment: Great! It makes sense now. Two questions though; First, I need to create the rectangle within the createButton function, how would I modify the createButton function to do that? Second, when I create the clickedButton(button,clickPt) function, would I just compare to see if the clicked point is within the points used when creating the rectangle object for my button?

Comment: I have added a comprehensive example that should answer most of your questions.

Comment: I'm in an entry level course and haven't been exposed to much of this :/. I'll try to "dummy" it down some..thanks for all of your help!

Comment: It the answer was useful, please mark it as accepted. There is a green tick under the votes.